# How to use Futures within Kafka Streams

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When using the `org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams` library in Scala, I have been trying to read in an inputStream, pass that information over to a method: `validateAll(infoToValidate)` that returns a Future, resolve that and then send to an output stream.

Example:

```
builder.stream[String, Object](REQUEST_TOPIC)
      .mapValues(v => ValidateFormat.from(v.asInstanceOf[GenericRecord]))
      .mapValues(infoToValidate => {
        SuccessFailFormat.to(validateAll(infoToValidate))
      })
```

Is there any documentation on performing this? I have looked into filter() and transform() but still not sure how to deal with Futures in KStreams.

Comment: Why not `.get()` the Future?

Comment: @cricket_007 you can't `.get()` a Future in scala. You would have to perform a map on it or an Await

Comment: I'm not an expert, but seems like KStreams interface is inherently synchronous. This probably means that you'd need to cross the sync/async boundary in your code - with `Await.result` + handle errors/timeouts as necessary + managing the threadpool for the futures execution context. I think this is not a shortsight, but a design decision - it makes sure that messages are not reordered.

Comment: Well, however it's done (I'm only familiar with Java futures). Basically, I'm in agreement with John here. And by the way, if you used the schema registry, it would validate the "format" of messages on its own

Comment: What's the signature for `ValidateFormat.from` and `SuccessFailFormat.to` and `validateAll`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends whether you need to preserve the original order of your messages. If yes, then you will have to block in one way or the other. For example:

```
val duration = 10 seconds // whatever your timeout should be or Duration.Inf
sourceStream
  .mapValues(x => Await.result(validate(x), duration))
  .to(outputTopic)
```

If however the order is not important, you can simply use a Kafka producer:

```
sourceStream
  .mapValues(x => validate(x)) // now you have KStream[.., Future[...]]
  .foreach { future =>
    future.foreach { item =>
      val record = new ProducerRecord(outputTopic, key, item)
      producer.send(record) // provided you have the implicit serializer
    }
  }
```